# Google Sky Map open sourced - How to map click action to objects?

Tags: android

As Google Sky Map open sourced some days ago, I'm trying to play around with it. Unfortunately I'm unable to map user's click action to objects (planets, etc...).

The entry point for this is `GestureInterceptor.onDown(MotionEvent e)` I think.

But how do I map the `MotionEvent` to an object? I'm totally lost here.

You can find the source code here: http://code.google.com/p/stardroid/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fapp

What is came up with so far:

```
 AstronomerModel model = StardroidApplication.getModel();
 Pointing pointing = model.getPointing();
```

So I have the model and I can get the line of sight. But what needs to be done then is transform the click coordinates to geocentric coordinates (how?) and then find the object which is located at those coordinates (how?).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here's what I've done.

I captured the labels Geocentric Positions and stored all of them in the ApplicationConstants class. You can get them in the ProtobufAstronomicalSource.getLabels(), except for the planets, wich you can get on PlanetSource.initialize().

Then, when the user clicks, the method onSingleTapConfirmed is called in the class com.google.android.stardroid.touch.GestureInterpreter. Inside this method I get all the labels, convert the Geocentric Postions into screen position, using this code:

```
    @Override
      public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Confirmed single tap");

        Point screen = ApplicationConstants.getSizeOfScreen();
        int screenHeight = screen.y;
        int screenWidth = screen.x;
        float yClicked = screenHeight - e.getRawY(); //e.y is inverted, this normalizes it
        float xClicked = e.getRawX();
        ArrayList<Label> labelArray = ApplicationConstants.getLabels();
        Log.d("LabelClicked", "label count: " + labelArray.size());
        ArrayList<LabelScreen> labelsOnScreen = new ArrayList<LabelScreen>();
        for (Label label : labelArray) {
            //calculets current screen position of all labels, most of this code comes from LabelObjectManager.drawLabel()
            Vector3 lookDir = ApplicationConstants.getLookDir();
            if (lookDir.x * label.x + lookDir.y * label.y + lookDir.z * label.z < ApplicationConstants.getmDotProductThreshold()) {
              //return;
            }

            Vector3 mLabelOffset = ApplicationConstants.getmLabelOffset();

            // Offset the label to be underneath the given position (so a label will 
            // always appear underneath a star no matter how the phone is rotated) 
            Vector3 v = new Vector3(
                label.x - mLabelOffset.x * label.offset,
                label.y - mLabelOffset.y * label.offset,
                label.z - mLabelOffset.z * label.offset);

            Vector3 screenPos = Matrix4x4.transformVector(
                ApplicationConstants.setTransformToScreenMatrix(),
                v);

            // We want this to align consistently with the pixels on the screen, so we
            // snap to the nearest x/y coordinate, and add a magic offset of less than
            // half a pixel.  Without this, rounding error can cause the bottom and
            // top of a label to be one pixel off, which results in a noticeable
            // distortion in the text.
            final float MAGIC_OFFSET = 0.25f;
            screenPos.x = (int)screenPos.x + MAGIC_OFFSET;
            screenPos.y = (int)screenPos.y + MAGIC_OFFSET;

            //by Marcio Granzotto Rodrigues
            if ((screenPos.x < 0.0f) | (screenPos.y < 0.0f)) {
                //not on screen
            }else if ((screenPos.x > screenWidth) | (screenPos.y > screenHeight)) {
                //not on screen
            }else if (screenPos.z < 0) {
                //not on screen
            }else {
                //on screen
                Log.d("LabelClicked", "on screen: " + label.getText() + " - " + screenPos.x + " " + screenPos.y + " " + screenPos.z);
                LabelScreen labelScreen = new LabelScreen(label, screenPos);
                labelsOnScreen.add(labelScreen);
            }//end else
        }//end for

        Log.i("LabelClicked", "Labels on Screen: " + labelsOnScreen.size());
        LabelScreen theLabel = null;
        for (LabelScreen labelScreen : labelsOnScreen) {
            if (true) { //TODO check if label is on the clickable list
                if (theLabel == null) {
                    //defines first label
                    theLabel = labelScreen;
                    Log.i("LabelClicked", "theLabel null -> " + theLabel.getLabel().getText());
                }else {
                    //check if this label is closer to the click area than theLabel
                    float theLabelRelativeX = theLabel.getScreenPos().x - xClicked; 
                    float theLabelRelativeY = theLabel.getScreenPos().y - yClicked;
                    float myLabelRealativeX = labelScreen.getScreenPos().x - xClicked;
                    float myLabelRealativeY = labelScreen.getScreenPos().y - yClicked;

                    if ((Math.abs(myLabelRealativeX) < Math.abs(theLabelRelativeX)) 
                            && (Math.abs(myLabelRealativeY) < Math.abs(theLabelRelativeY))) {
                        Log.i("LabelClicked", "theLabel " + theLabel.getLabel().getText() + " -> " + labelScreen.getLabel().getText());
                        theLabel = labelScreen;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        float theLabelRelativeX = theLabel.getScreenPos().x - xClicked; 
        float theLabelRelativeY = theLabel.getScreenPos().y - yClicked;
        if ((theLabelRelativeX < screenWidth*0.1f) && (theLabelRelativeY < screenHeight*0.1f)) {
            //clicked
            if (theLabel.getLabel().getText().equals(ApplicationConstants.myContext.getString(com.google.android.stardroid.R.string.moon))) {
                //ìf the clicked label is the moon, checks phase (in portuguese)
                String moonPhase = "";
                switch (ApplicationConstants.getMoonPhase()) {
                case ApplicationConstants.MOON_FULL:
                    moonPhase = " cheia";
                    break;
                case ApplicationConstants.MOON_CRESCENT:
                    moonPhase = " crescente";
                    break;
                case ApplicationConstants.MOON_NEW:
                    moonPhase = " nova";
                    break;
                case ApplicationConstants.MOON_GIBBOUS:
                    moonPhase = " minguante";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                Toast.makeText(ApplicationConstants.myContext, theLabel.getLabel().getText() + moonPhase, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("LabelClicked", "You clicked: " + theLabel.getLabel().getText() + moonPhase);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(ApplicationConstants.myContext, theLabel.getLabel().getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("LabelClicked", "You clicked: " + theLabel.getLabel().getText());
            }
        }
        return false;
      }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please Share ApplicationContants class